# NZSQL/Code - LEFT() Function in Netezza NZ-SQL

Tags: sql, netezza

Everyone!

I am trying to find how to use, or a replacement for the LEFT() function for Netezza/NZSQL.

What I need is to grab the first two charectors of a string. The code I used to use in TSQL is as follows:

```
LEFT(COLUMN_A,2) AS Column_Name
```

is there a similar function in NZSQL? When I type in "LEFT" it turns grey, but is not recognized as a function and acts like it is misisng another part...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the built in function SUBSTR() or you can use the STRLEFT() function that is included with the SQL Extension Toolkit. The latter option will only be available if it has been installed.

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select SUBSTR('ABCDED',1,2);
 SUBSTR
--------
 AB
(1 row)
```

or

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> select STRLEFT('ABCDED',2);
 STRLEFT
---------
 AB
(1 row)
```

Comment: Unfortunately we have not had the extension installed just yet, but the first option did it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do string right strright

```
select sql_functions..STRright('Value of Field',5);
```